# What setting causes my autoindent to add indent on a new line?

Tags: indentation, filetype-go

I have this `go` code snippet that I am working on in vim with `vim-go` enabled. `|` is where my cursor is at.

```
// PlayerServer is a HTTP interface for player information
type PlayerServer struct {
        store  PlayerStore |
        router *http.ServeMux
}
```

When I hit return, the cursor goes 8 spaces indented in the next line.

```
// PlayerServer is a HTTP interface for player information
type PlayerServer struct {
        store  PlayerStore 
                |
        router *http.ServeMux
}
```

What setting should I be looking at to see what causes this?

Comment: What does `:set filetype?` say? Is the file correctly recognized as Go source code? What about `:set indentexpr?`, does it match the Go plug-in you're using? (Just making sure everything is as expected to be in your environment.) Feel free to answer these with edits to your question.

Comment: Your comment made me look at those settings, I went through vim-go doc and realized I hadn't set `filetype plugin indent on`. That solved the issue. Thanks a bunch! If you add that as an answer I'd be happy to mark it solved.

Comment: I imagine there might be a duplicate for this question, but I did a quick search and couldn't find an obvious one... If anybody finds one that's appropriate, please mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As diagnosed through comments, you were probably using some generic indentation (such as Vim's `cindent`, which is likely to expect semi-colons to end statements.)

In order to enable language-specific plugins for indentation, enable filetype detection and filetype indentation plugins, with:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Comment: Also, dont set cindent in your vimrc :P